# Django Longint in Mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

my project was not working properly when switching from my local development (sqlite3) to mysql. After some inspection, I found that Django seems to use 32-bit-ints for IntegerField on mysql, but I need 64 bit. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BigIntegerField` for 64 bit integers.

Comment: There is no field like this in the latest 1.1 stable.

Comment: It's in 1.2, if you can't use that then you'll need to make a custom field.